Blurry, smudged text in some applications on Windows 10
Problem
I am experiencing an issue with unreadable text on windows 10. This occurs only in some applications. For Example TeamSpeak and Arduino IDE. Due to inactiveness (?) within these windows or sometimes even when the window is active, the text is getting unreadable and very smudgy, blurry. As seen in this screenshot:

I tried

enabling or disabling cleartype with different cleartype settings
installing/using mactype with disabled cleartype
searching every inch in all the system settings
googling the hell out of it; all my research ends with other issues

My System:
I have a decent setup with an

Nvidia RTX 7400 TI, latest driver installed. also occured with the previous two driver releases
LG UltraGear 27GR95QE OLED Display
2.560x1.440 WQHD without scaling, no text scaling either

What else can I try? How do I make this bug disappear?

Does this occur in Chrome or Edge? I don't know what's up here, but it sounds like it exclusively affects Electron-based (i.e. Chrome-based) apps?

No. It doesn't happen in Chrome, Firefox, Brave etc.

Just to be clear, you are saying Arduino IDE renders normally for a while and then suddenly looks bad as shown in the screenshot?
